# Creating .csv based on values in dictionary

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I'm trying to parse an XML file, return the values and put it into a .csv file. I have the following code so far:

```
for shift_i in shift_list :

    # Iterates through all values in 'shift_list' for later comparison to ensure all tags are only counted once
    for node in tree.xpath("//Data/Status[@Name and @Reason]"):
    # Iterates through all nodes containing a 'Name' and 'Reason' attribute
        state = node.attrib["Name"]
        reason = node.attrib["Reason"]
        end = node.attrib["End"]
        start = node.attrib[u'Start']
        # Sets each of the attribute values to the name of the attribute all lowercase
        try:
        shift = node.attrib[u'Shift']
        except:
            continue
        # Tries to set shift attribute value to 'shift' variable, sometimes fails if no Shift attribute is present
        if shift == shift_i :
        # If the Shift attribute is equal to the current iteration from the 'shift_list', takes the difference of start and end and appends that value to the list with the given Name, Reason, and Shift
            tdelta = datetime.strptime(end, FMT) - datetime.strptime(start, FMT)
            d[state, reason, shift].append((tdelta.total_seconds()) / 60)

    for node in tree.xpath("//Data/Status[not(@Reason)]"):
    # Iterates through Status nodes with no Reason attribute
        state = node.attrib["Name"]
        end = node.attrib["End"]
        start = node.attrib[u'Start']
        # Sets each of the attribute values to the name of the attribute all lowercase
        try:
            shift = node.attrib[u'Shift']
        except:
            continue
        # Tries to set shift attribute value to 'shift' variable, sometimes fails if no Shift
        #      attribute is present
        if shift == shift_i:
            # If the Shift attribute is equal to the current iteration from the 'shift_list',
            #   takes the difference of start and end and appends that value to the list with
            #   the given Name, "No Reason" string, and Shift
            tdelta = datetime.strptime(end, FMT) - datetime.strptime(start, FMT)
            d[state, 'No Reason', shift].append((tdelta.total_seconds()) / 60)

    for item in d :
     # Iterates through all items of d
        d[item] = sum(d[item])
        # Sums all values related to 'item' and replaces value in dictionary
    a.update(d)
    # Current keys and values in temporary dictionary 'd' to permanent
    #   dictionary 'a' for further analysis
    d.clear()
    # Clears dictionary d of current iterations keys and values to start fresh for next
    #   iteration. If this is not done, d[item] = sum(d[item]) returns
    #   "TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable"
```

This creates a dictionary with values that look like this:

```
{('Name1','Reason','Shift'):Value,('Name2','Reason','Shift'):Value....}
```

print(a) returns this

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {('Test Run', 'No Reason', 'Night'): 5.03825, ('Slow Running', 'No Reason', 'Day'): 10.72996666666667, ('Idle', 'Shift Start Up', 'Day'): 5.425433333333333, ('Idle', 'Unscheduled', 'Afternoon'): 470.0, ('Idle', 'Early Departure', 'Day'): 0.32965, ('Idle', 'Break Creep', 'Day'): 24.754250000000003, ('Idle', 'Break', 'Day'): 40.0, ('Micro Stoppage', 'No Reason', 'Day'): 39.71673333333333, ('Idle', 'Unscheduled', 'Night'): 474.96175, ('Running', 'No Reason', 'Day'): 329.4991500000004, ('Idle', 'No Reason', 'Day'): 19.544816666666666})
```

I want to create a .csv that has columns of 'Names'+'Reasons' with the totals, and the rows are described by the 'Shift'. Like this:

```
         Name1-Reason    Name2-Reason    Name3-Reason    Name4-Reason
Shift1      value          value            value           value
Shift2      value          value            value           value
Shift3      value          value            value           value
```

I'm not sure how to go about doing this. I tried using nested Dicts to better describe my data but I got a TypeError when using

```
d[state][reason][shift].append((tdelta.total_seconds()) / 60)
```

If there is a better way to do this please let me know, I'm a very new to this and would love to hear all advice.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what's into the dictionary? What is `Value` for example?

Comment: I don't think your dictionary looks like `{('Name','Reason','Shift'):Value,('Name','Reason','Shift'):Value....}` because all the keys are the same. How does it really look?

Comment: The indentation of your code is messed up which makes it difficult to follow. Please [edit] your question and fix this. While you're at it, if you could also show the contents of the dictionary `d` after it's populated that would make answering you question much easier.

Comment: @martineau I've edited my comment to hopefully make it more clear what I'm trying to do. Thank you again for taking the time to help me. Let me know if there is anything else I should provide.

Comment: just an idea, depending on your preferred parsing methods you might also consider entering the data into a Pandas data frame instead of a dict and then using `pandas.DataFrame.to_csv`. I've found exporting CSV from these dataframes to be relatively painless. Docs [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html). Of course if you're not familiar with Pandas this would also require learning how to import the data.

Comment: " I tried using nested Dicts to better describe my data but I got a TypeError when using " also did you try initializing `d[state]` as a `defaultdict` as well?

Comment: It's also unclear how you want to map data in the dictionary to rows of the csv. "Name" and "Shift" are fairly obvious, but how does "value" relate to "reason". Perhaps if you could show us what the content of `a` would look like if it was converted into the a csv.

Comment: @martineau I've updated the post. Reason breaks down the Name into more categories. i.e. Name1 maybe have two reasons (Name1-Reason1, Name2-Reason2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following may do what you want or at least be close. One important consideration that was ignored by the way you say the CSV file should be formatted, is the fact that each row must have a `Name-Reason` column for *every possible* combination of the two, even if there weren't any of that particular mixture in any of the shift rows — because, well, that's just how the CSV file format works.

```
from collections import defaultdict
import csv

# Dictionary keys are (Name, Reason, Shift)
d = {('Test Run', 'No Reason', 'Night'): 5.03825,
     ('Slow Running', 'No Reason', 'Day'): 10.72996666666667,
     ('Idle', 'Shift Start Up', 'Day'): 5.425433333333333,
     ('Idle', 'Unscheduled', 'Afternoon'): 470.0,
     ('Idle', 'Early Departure', 'Day'): 0.32965,
     ('Idle', 'Break Creep', 'Day'): 24.754250000000003,
     ('Idle', 'Break', 'Day'): 40.0,
     ('Micro Stoppage', 'No Reason', 'Day'): 39.71673333333333,
     ('Idle', 'Unscheduled', 'Night'): 474.96175,
     ('Running', 'No Reason', 'Day'): 329.4991500000004,
     ('Idle', 'No Reason', 'Day'): 19.544816666666666}

# Transfer data to a defaultdict of dicts.
dd = defaultdict(dict)
for (name, reason, shift), value in d.items():
    name_reason = name + '-' + reason  # Merge together to form lower level keys
    dd[shift][name_reason] = value

# Create a csv file from the data in the defaultdict.
ABSENT = '---'  # Placeholder for empty fields
name_reasons = sorted(name_reason for shift in dd.keys()
                                    for name_reason in dd[shift])
with open('dict.csv', 'wb') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    writer.writerow(['Shift'] + name_reasons)  # column headers row
    for shift in sorted(dd):
        row = [shift] + [dd[shift].get(name_reason, ABSENT)
                                        for name_reason in name_reasons]
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Here's the contents of the `dict.csv` file the code above creates:

```
Shift,Idle-Break,Idle-Break Creep,Idle-Early Departure,Idle-No Reason,Idle-Shift Start Up,Idle-Unscheduled,Idle-Unscheduled,Micro Stoppage-No Reason,Running-No Reason,Slow Running-No Reason,Test Run-No Reason
Afternoon,---,---,---,---,---,470.0,470.0,---,---,---,---
Day,40.0,24.754250000000003,0.32965,19.544816666666666,5.425433333333333,---,---,39.71673333333333,329.4991500000004,10.72996666666667,---
Night,---,---,---,---,---,474.96175,474.96175,---,---,---,5.03825
```

Comment: I apologize for not accepting this answer sooner. Was reading my old posts after being here for a while. Thanks again for taking the time to help younger me.

Comment: TMarks: You're belatedly welcome — better late than never IMO. `;¬)`

Answer (score 1):

I would use the DictWriter method of the csv package to write your csv file. For that you need to have a list of dictionaries. Each list item is a `shift` and is represented by a dictionary with keys `name` & `reason`. It should look like the following:

`[{'Name1':value1, 'Name2':value2}, {'Name1':value3, 'Name2':value4}]`